# Displaying the cloud free composite of Sentinel2 using s2cloudless in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, cloudmasking

I applied the tutorial  for 'Sentinel-2 Cloud Masking with s2cloudless' and have this script in GEE:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c525b3926841d4953e016e64682a4e5c

In this tutorial, I do not understand the  purpose of 'cloud transform' layer and I do not know how to display the final cloud free image.
Should I apply a median to see the final result? If yes, over which layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of 'cloud transform' is to estimate projection of cloud shadows based on cloud position and sun azimuth. Or, as the author specifies it `// Project shadows from clouds for the distance specified by the CLD_PRJ_DIST input.`

Then, if you want to display the cloud-free **image**, you need to apply all those masks using `apply_cld_shdw_mask()` function.
Here is a result: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0701d40fb1f844cfd376e8e6cbd7d946

However, if you want to make a cloud-free **composite**, you have to map this function over many images and then reduce them into a composite (e.g. take median). Here is a result:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9aaa276f0fa1ab33e78230e8f348c6f

Comment: Thanks @Basile, this solved my problem. I was after the composite as you mentioned